# Montar menu com Filtro e Subfiltro

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando montar um menu onde deveria mostrar o Filtro e Subfiltro, estou conseguindo montar a descrição do Filtro mas o Subfiltro ainda não.

O que está acontecendo é que ele começa a montar o subfiltro e não "quebra" para o próximo, ficando como está no visual do site, o mesmo deveria ficar assim:

```
Tampo
- Vidro
Formato
- Redondo
Largura
- 0,51m - 1,00
- 1,01m - 1,50
Lugares
- 1 lugar
- 2 lugares
Material
- Metal
- Couro Sintético
```

[Echo das variáveis dos id_filtro](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1&sub=4)

Vejam como está minha *query*:

```
if ($dep != ""  and $sub != "") {   

$arrayProdutos = "";
$arrayFiltros = "";

// COMEÇANDO O MENU
while($row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa)) {               

    if ($arrayProdutos == "") { 
        $arrayProdutos = $row_rsPesquisa['id_produto'];                     
    } else {
        $arrayProdutos = $arrayProdutos . "," .$row_rsPesquisa['id_produto'];
    }

}

    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_filtro = "SELECT 
                          filtro.id_filtro,
                          filtro.descricao
                        FROM
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro
                          INNER JOIN filtro ON (produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro = filtro.id_filtro)
                        WHERE
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_produto IN ($arrayProdutos)
                          GROUP BY
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro";
    $filtro = mysql_query($query_filtro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_filtro = mysql_fetch_assoc($filtro);                                           
    $totalRows_filtro = mysql_num_rows($filtro);

// MOSTRANDO MENU
while($row_filtro = mysql_fetch_assoc($filtro)) {

    // MONTANDO VALORES PARA O SUBFILTRO
    if ($arrayFiltros == "") { 
        $arrayFiltros = $row_filtro['id_filtro'];                       
    } else {
        $arrayFiltros = $arrayFiltros . "," .$row_filtro['id_filtro'];
    }

echo 
  "<ul class='menu2'>
    <li><a href='#'>$row_filtro[descricao]</a></li>
    <li class='current-menu-item'></li>                
  </ul>";   
// FIM DO MENNU                 

    // COMEÇANDO O SUBMENU              
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_subfiltro = "SELECT 
                          subfiltro.descricao
                        FROM
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro
                          INNER JOIN subfiltro ON (produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_subfiltro = subfiltro.id_subfiltro)
                        WHERE
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro IN ($arrayFiltros) AND 
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_produto IN ($arrayProdutos)
                        GROUP BY
                          subfiltro.descricao";
    $subfiltro = mysql_query($query_subfiltro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_subfiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($subfiltro);                                         
    $totalRows_subfiltro = mysql_num_rows($subfiltro);

    while($row_subfiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($subfiltro)) {

        $descProdutoSub = $row_subfiltro['descricao'];

    echo 
      "<ul class='menu2'>
        <li><a href='#'>$descProdutoSub</a></li>
      </ul>";
    }

    // FIM DO SUBMENU
}

echo $arrayFiltros;
}
```

Estrutura das tabelas do menu do submenu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @QMechanic73, obrigado pela dica, sim, tenho consciência do risco, mas estou tentando acertar esse problema do meu menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema do meu menu de filtro e subfiltro, depois de horas testando, percebi que o que estava dando errado era a posição do meu WHILE, inicialmente fiz assim:

```
while($row_rsSubFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubFiltro)) {

}
```

O comando estava falhando e fiz a inversão, ficando assim:

```
do {

} while($row_rsSubFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubFiltro));
```

O resultado pode ser visto aqui:

[Filtro e Subfiltro sendo exibido de forma correta](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=1&sub=4)